# Check RTMP broadcast quality

Tags: flash, audio, video, streaming, rtmp

Is there a way to find the quality of RTMP broadcast in a Flash client?

If a client has a bad network issue which results in a poor audio or video broadcast, how can I detect it on the Flash client or on the media server and show indication to the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using netstream to receive video on the flash client side, you can get the stream delay and fps of the video. This can help in getting some useful data about the quality. eg. stream.currentFPs will give you the fps.

Again, it depends how you are subscribing to the video on the client side.

Comment: I'm broadcasting audio with a netstream but more interested in the broadcaster side not the subscriber. Is it possible to check the quality there?

Comment: At the braodcasting side, it's tricky, since the client will just keep pushing packets, irrespective of network conditions. It should be possible to analyze the stream received at the server side though and determine its quality. The server you used should give you apis/options to do that.

Comment: How would you implement this on the server? I'm using a RTMP lib and have control on the server.

Comment: How about this. You can have a simple test code that subscribes to the audio at the server itself, and monitor the fps etc. Since the subscribing channel is not the bottleneck here, you can assume that loss of fps/delay etc. is because of the publisher. But depending on your server (Wowza, Red5?) you should be able to do something smarter. May need to go through the server documentation for that.

Comment: Let's say I'm using Red5. What exactly do I need to monitor for audio and for video? Doesn't pfs depends on how much movement the webcam has?

Comment: No fps doesn't (shouldn't) depend on that.